# How to build a ctypes array of structure in python

Tags: python, arrays, structure, ctypes

**Purpose**

Deliver an array of structure from python module to c module.

**Method**

Leverage python ctypes to call c api to transfer data.

**Steps**

1. Declare structure prototype in python; (pass, line 4-9)
2. Define the array of structures; (pass, line 16-17)
3. Fill values to this array; (failed, line 30)

**C API Declaration**

```
injectNodes(int nodeNum, struct node *pNode);

struct node {
    uint16_t id;
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t depth;
};
```

**Python Code**

```
#!/bin/python3
import pdb
from ctypes import *
class Node(Structure):
    _field_ = [
        ("id",    c_uint16),
        ("version", c_uint8),
        ("depth",    c_uint8)
    ]

dics = [{'ID': '3', 'VERSION': '180', 'DEPTH': '924'},
        {'ID': '9', 'VERSION': '180', 'DEPTH': '269'},
        {'ID': '2', 'VERSION': '180', 'DEPTH': '537'}]

nodeNum = len(dics)
NODES = Node * nodeNum
nodes = NODES()
for j in range(nodeNum):
    print(dics[j])
    node = Node()
    node.id = int(dics[j]["ID"])
    node.version = int(dics[j]["VERSION"])
    node.depth = int(dics[j]["DEPTH"])
    print("id", node.id)
    print("version", node.version)
    print("depth", node.depth)
    nodes[j] = node
    print("id", nodes[j].id)
    print("version", nodes[j].version)
    print("depth", nodes[j].depth)
print(nodes)
```

**Expected Results**

```
{'ID': '3', 'DEPTH': '924', 'VERSION': '180'}
id 3
version 180
depth 924
id 3
version 180
depth 924
{'ID': '9', 'DEPTH': '269', 'VERSION': '180'}
id 9
version 180
depth 269
id 9
version 180
depth 269
{'ID': '2', 'DEPTH': '537', 'VERSION': '180'}
id 2
version 180
depth 537
id 2
version 180
depth 537
```

**Actual Results**

```
{'ID': '3', 'DEPTH': '924', 'VERSION': '180'}
id 3
version 180
depth 924
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "array_test.py", line 28, in <module>
    print("id", nodes[j].id)
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: I have set nodes[j] in line "nodes[j] = node", i don't know why nodes[j] still don't have the attributes 'rank'. please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's **`_fields_` (plural), not** `_field_`.

Answer (score 0):

`Structure` must have a definition of `_fields_` not `__field__`.

There is another error as well.  `depth` is declared as `c_uint8` which has a range of 0-255, but the values in the dictionary are all greater than 255.

I suggest defining `__repr__` in the structure so `Node` can print itself, and using more "pythonic" looping:

```
from ctypes import *

class Node(Structure):

    _fields_ = [("id", c_uint16),
                ("version", c_uint8),
                ("depth", c_uint8)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Node(id={self.id}, version={self.version}, depth={self.depth})'

dics = [{'ID': '3', 'VERSION': '180', 'DEPTH': '924'},
        {'ID': '9', 'VERSION': '180', 'DEPTH': '269'},
        {'ID': '2', 'VERSION': '180', 'DEPTH': '537'}]

nodeNum = len(dics)
NODES = Node * nodeNum
nodes = NODES()

for node,dic in zip(nodes,dics):
    node.id = int(dic['ID'])
    node.version = int(dic['VERSION'])
    node.depth = int(dic['DEPTH'])

for node in nodes:
    print(node)
```

Output (`depth` is module 256 due to its `c_uint8` definition):

```
Node(id=3, version=180, depth=156)
Node(id=9, version=180, depth=13)
Node(id=2, version=180, depth=25)
```